# TextField with Kotlin StateFlow

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow

I'd like to have a `TextField` bound to a `MutableStateFlow` that comes from a view model. This is how I set it up:

```
@Composable
fun MyTextField(textFlow: MutableStateFlow<String>) {
    val state = textFlow.collectAsState(initial = "")
    TextField(
        value = TextFieldValue(state.value),
        onValueChange = { textFlow.value = it.text },
        label = { Text(text = "Label") }
    )
}
```

When I type something into the text field, it behaves really strangely. For example, if I type 'asd', it ends up with 'asdasa'. How can I update `textFlow.value` without messing up with the text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused by the usage of [`TextFieldValue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/input/TextFieldValue) with [`Flow`](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow).

To fix this, set the `value` of the `TextField` to just `state.value` and then on text change set the value with `textFlow.value = it`.

```
@Composable
fun MyTextField(textFlow: MutableStateFlow<String>) {
    val state = textFlow.collectAsState(initial = "")
    TextField(
        value = state.value,
        onValueChange = { textFlow.value = it },
        label = { Text(text = "Label") }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `MutableStateFlow` as the backing for a `TextField` (as of Compose 1.5 and earlier). You should prefer `MutableState` instead. See [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/effective-state-management-for-textfield-in-compose-d6e5b070fbe5) for an in depth explanation of why.